# Notepad++ Return ONLY content within an XML Tag

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

I have a HUGE set of XML documents that have very specific tags.  I'm looking to remove everything [EXCEPT] the content within a tag called :

```
<DisplayContents>
    <ID>8</ID>
    <Type>102</Type>
    <Contents>A whole bunch of stuff in this tag</Contents>
</DisplayContents>
```

In this example I would simply want to see the text *A whole bunch of stuff in this tag*

I've tried to use:

```
<(Contents).*?>|</.(Contents)>
```

as a Regex and Mark the lines... then remove the unmarked.  But that seems to remove everything :(  So - I'm doing something wrong and it is likely because I'm not much of a Regex guru.

**EDIT:  The stuff within Contents is very long and spans many lines with line feeds, in case that is what is tripping this up. **

Comment: If it is possible try using a xml parser instead.

Comment: Obligatory link about [the futility of parsing XML with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/62576) instead of using a DOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you wish to remove everything except,

```
A whole bunch of stuff in this tag
```

for which maybe an expression similar to,

```
<DisplayContents>[\s\S]*?<Contents>(.*?)<\/Contents>[\s\S]*?<\/DisplayContents>
```

being replaced with `$1` might work.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xLysIO/1/)

Comment: I guess I should have said the XML above is a small snippet of what is in the file.  There are more XML tags everywhere.  I pasted the code into the demo and it shows No Matches.  I'll play around and see what I can figure out.